# Rewriting mutable/imperative loop as functional

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
    var lastSize = 0                                                                                                                 
    var all = entries                                                       
    while(lastSize != all.size){                                            
        entries = entries.flatMap(                                          
            _.instructions.iterator.asScala                                 
            .flatMap(_ match {                                              
                case m:MethodInsnNode => Some(MethodCall(m.owner, m.name, m.desc))               
                case _ => None                                              
            })                                                              
        ).toSet.flatMap(findMethod _)                                       
        lastSize = all.size                                                 
        all = all.union(entries)                                            
    }
```

My code uses ASM to generate a `Set` of all potential `MethodNode`s that could be called from a given starting set, `entries`. However, I want to rewrite it in a functional manner. The repeated mapping of sets definitely seems recursive, though I can't entirely wrap my head around how to go about it.

---

I came up with this, though it uses slightly different (but working?) logic. Would it be possible to write it with tail-call recursion?

```
private def gatherMethods(current: Set[MethodNode]): Set[MethodNode] = {    
    val next = current.flatMap(                                             
        _.instructions.iterator.asScala                                     
        .flatMap(_ match {                                                  
            case m:MethodInsnNode => Some(MethodCall(m.owner, m.name, m.desc))
            case _ => None                                                  
        })                                                                  
    ).toSet.flatMap(findMethod _)                                           
    if(next == current) Set()                                               
    else current.union(gatherMethods(next))                                 
}
```

Comment: Can you please post an [MCVE] of your problem? What is `MethodNode` and `MethodInsnNode`?

Comment: It looks to me as if you could simply add an accumulator and return that instead of the empty set at the end of your recursion but it's impossible to verify that unless you post a more complete (preferably simplified) example of what all these objects are as well as some input/expected output.

Comment: Too many undefined symbols. `MethodInsnNode`, `MethodCall`, `MethodNode`, `findMethod`.

Comment: ASM is a library that loads Java classes and is able to inspect them in detail. `MethodNode`s represent Java methods. I map over the bytecode instructions to find calls to other methods (`MethodInsnNode`). `findMethod` finds and returns the corresponding `MethodNode`, which is only given as Strings from the instructions. The end goal is to compile a `Set` of all methods that could be called from a manually given `MethodNode`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov My focus was mainly to replace the `while` loop with something more functional. I went into a bit more detail above eitherway.